# how to display record on one page with continues record number and create new header column?

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a problem, on design lay out crystal report,
I want to display like this,

[lay out report image](http://s13.postimg.org/e82sirp53/ask.png)

I have been looking for on google, but not found. I confuse what is the right keyword in google. Please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Crystal Reports, create a running total that is based on the field you want to count. The type of summary will be count. Evaluate for each record and never reset. Add the field and running total to the report detail section. That will show you a count of all your records.